# Get sum of two columns in one LINQ query without grouping

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I want to sum up three different fields of a table in one query. I want a linq equivalent of this T-SQL:

```
select sum(fld1), SUM(fld2),  SUM(fld3)   from MyTable where classID = 5
```

All examples I have found either use a group by or call the query multiple times, once for each field that needs to be summed up.

I have something like this now. But I don't want to add a group by clause to it as it is not required in its T-SQL form.

```
from a in MyTable
where a.classID == 5
group a by a.classID into g
select new 
{
Sumfld1 =  g.Sum(x => x.fld1 ), 
Sumfld2 = g.Sum(x => x.fld2),
Sumfld3 = g.Sum(x => x.fld3)
}
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can use `group a by 1 into g` to apply necessary group by with no effect.

Comment: Does it really make a practical difference not to introduce the group by clause? How long is the query taking both ways?

Comment: why are you grouping on classId when you also filter on classId. Why not just drop the group?

Comment: esben: I want to drop the group hence this post. Unfortunately that is the only way I know to use the SUM operation

Comment: enigma: This is a simple query as an example. A Group By clause will add to the execution time in more complex queries. Plus T-SQL doesnt need a group by for summation so why does LinQ?

Comment: mella: using the group by 1 into g resulted in a subquery under the cover when I checked in profiler where as using the field name resulted in a simple query, although it did have the group by [fieldname] attached. So not sure which is better here.

Answer (score 13):

As it turns out, in linq-to-sql you can get very close by doing:

```
from a in MyTable
where a.classID == 5
group a by 0 into g
select new 
{
    Sumfld1 = g.Sum(x => x.fld1), 
    Sumfld2 = g.Sum(x => x.fld2),
    Sumfld3 = g.Sum(x => x.fld3)
}
```

(note the group by **0**)

It does not translate into a sql `GROUP BY`, but a `SELECT` of multiple `SUM`s from a subquery. In terms of execution plan it may even be the same.

Entity Framework still creates a `GROUP BY`, albeit by `0`.

Comment: This will fail for MySQL. It will throw the error: "Unknown column '0' in 'group statement'"!

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = from a in MyTable 
        where a.classID == 5 
        select a;

int? Sumfld1 = x.Sum(y => y.fld1);
int? Sumfld2 = x.Sum(y => y.fld2);
int? Sumfld3 = x.Sum(y => y.fld3);
```

Comment: this looks like it will call the query in var X for every x.Sum(..)  Will try it and report back. Thanks.

Comment: @user20358 WHAT DID YOU FIND OUT?

Comment: It will do three queries