# EntityFramework how to: select Max(Column), Count(*) from Table

Tags: entity-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get sum of two columns in one LINQ query without grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239987/get-sum-of-two-columns-in-one-linq-query-without-grouping)

how to select Max and Count in one call using EF?

```
Select Max([Column]), Count(*) from [Table]
```

Comment: I can't think of anything that would do it in one call. Well except ExecuteStoreCommand which I assume could do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fake it grouping by `0`. SQL Server will see through that constant group-by and eliminate it. It has no runtime cost.

The question is: Will EF translate this to SQL properly? Given the track record (in contrast to good old trusty LINQ to SQL!) this is in doubt.